# spark sql percentile over floating point column

Tags: hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

According to the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/api/sql/#percentile) the percentile command should give the exact percentile for every numeric column. At least when my input is composed of floating points - this is not true.

In [hive docs,](https://support.treasuredata.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001457367-Hive-Built-in-Aggregate-Functions) it says the percentile command only works for integers. I didn't understand the relation between spark sql and hive, but it seems spark doesn't just run hive - otherwise it wouldn't have changed it's docs. Also, spark's `percentile` has a different signature, allowing it to get a `frequency` parameter, which I also have no idea what purpose it serves.
This is an example with unexpected output:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf

d = spark.createDataFrame([[35.138071000000004], [34.119932999999996], [34.487992]], ['a'])
d.select(sf.expr('percentile(a, array(0.25,0.5,0.75,0.9,0.95)) AS res')).collect()

Out[1]: [Row(res=[34.3039625, 34.487992, 34.8130315, 35.0080552, 35.0730631])]
```

If I switch `sf.expr` content to `percentile_approx` with a high accuracy, or use high `frequency` in the current method - I get a reasonable output.
Could you explain what's happening?

Also:

1. Can you please explain/point me to some resource about the relation between spark sql and apache hive?
2. Where is the code that spark sql commands run?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct relation between Spark and Hive except Spark's ability to retrieve metadata from Hive MetaStore regarding databases, tables and views defined in Hive. You can get familiar with Spark by reading its [online documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/).

SparkSQL is a completely independent (from Hive) implementation of SQL language written in Scala. [SparkSQL](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html) is one of Spark's modules that uses Spark cluster computing platform. Along with other Spark modules, it can run on Spark's own cluster (aka standalone), or make the use of YARN or Mesos.

Specifically, the [`percentile`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#percentile) function in SparkSQL according to SparkSQL documentation...

> Returns the exact percentile value of numeric column *col* at the given
>   percentage. The value of percentage must be between 0.0 and 1.0. The
>   value of frequency should be positive integral.

**EDIT**

Frequency parameter was added to the `percentile` function as part of [SPARK-18940](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18940), to be able to optionally supply extra column (generally speaking, an expression) that contains distribution of the analyzed values. The default value is `frequency = 1L`. 
There is a follow-up [SPARK-27929](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27929) that will relax the requirement to have it as type Long.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain the output I got?

Comment: @TzahiT your result provides 25th, 50th, etc. percentiles based on three input values, no? I also added some information about `frequency` parameter to my answer.

Comment: No, the input has 3 values, lets call them `a<b<c`. The output is:
`a<p25<p50=b<p75<p90<p95<c`. It's weird enough that the percentiles aren't parts of input values, but the output when compared to the input has no sense.

Comment: If I were to draw a normal distribution being given just three data points, I would probably end up with similar answer :) Maybe you can try running it against larger sample?

Comment: I just tried to avoid "testing" how this function works - this is just something I saw and "jumped". I don't understand, how does the function works? Doesn't it compute the result in an equivalent to ordering the data and picking the desired elements? Does it try to simulate a normal distribution that would most likely give these data points (is this hinted somewhere)? It looks like there's not enough info in the docs. Do you know where can I see the source code?

Comment: Googling "git sparksql percentile" gives https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/aggregate/Percentile.scala